# Is it legal for a Canadian airline to alter the price of a multi-flight booking after the initial payment and confirmation?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, canada

Suppose a customer in the UK books multiple flights with a Canadian airline via telephone.

Say the flights include:
 - Flights from the UK to Canada
 - Flights from the USA to Canada
 - Flights from Canada to the UK

On the telephone, the customer gives the details of the flights and receives a *single* quote (in CAD) for all the flights combined. The customer then pays using a debit card over the telephone. Later that day the customer receives an email confirming all the flight bookings. The booking information includes seat numbers.

6 weeks later, an auditor at the Canadian airline calls the customer and says that the price paid was incorrect. The auditor says that there was a mistake and one leg was not included in the quoted price. The auditor says that despite the confirmation email the customer will not be able to travel on that leg unless the additional amount is paid.

Are the actions of the Canadian airline legal? What action should the customer take?

Comment: On the face of it, this reeks of breach of contract. They make an offer, you accept and do not further investigate the competition since you relied on their offer, especially the price.

Comment: Uh, in the US, 14 CFR 399.88 spins the matter differently by calling it merely an "unfair and deceptive practice". However, USDOT announced about a year ago that they won't be enforcing that prohibition.  Canadian Transportation Agency apparently holds that if one party makes a fundamental mistake, the contract can be revoked. Essentially, they declare "there wasn't a contract to begin with". I'm trying to suppress the urge to lean on the exclamation-mark key.

Comment: Thank you very much @user6726. That information is very useful. It is a shame the consumer isn't better protected. :-(